# How can I read a file with text before the CSV header?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, keyerror

I am working with this database https://www.cryptodatadownload.com/cdd/Exmo_BTCEUR_1h.csv
and this error appeared when I tried to extract 'close' column

my code is the following:

```
> data= pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Downloads/btceur1h.csv')
BTC=pd.DataFrame(data)
BTC['close']
```

and this error occured:

```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2645             try:
-> 2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'close'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-e48080b9c83e> in <module>
----> 1 BTC['close']

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2798             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2799                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2800             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2801             if is_integer(indexer):
   2802                 indexer = [indexer]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:
-> 2648                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2649         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2650         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'close'
```

How can I avoid this issue??

Comment: Thats a text file, not a database. You're asking how to read a specific column from a Dataframe. Does that column actually exist? Is the file a *valid* CSV, or just a text report saved with a fake extension?

Comment: your `BTC` returns a `[28611 rows x 1 columns]` data frame

Answer (score 3):

That's a flat file, not a database. The first line contains a URL instead of field names:

```
https://www.CryptoDataDownload.com
unix,date,symbol,open,high,low,close,Volume EUR,Volume BTC
1629763200000,2021-08-24 00:00:00,BTC/EUR,42138.6,42304.29,42086.01,42219.58,5767.798367994,0.1366143
1629759600000,2021-08-23 23:00:00,BTC/EUR,42288.94,42335.66,42134.99,42185.41,7318.3523473165,0.17348065
```

You need to skip the first row. [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) allows you to specify an array of rows to skip through the `skiprows` parameter:

```
data= pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Downloads/btceur1h.csv', skiprows=[0])
```